# Bar chart doesn't load the charts

Tags: python, plotly

My code:

```
# Create website bar chart
website_fig = go.Bar(
        x=[
            today      + " - " + one_week,
            one_week   + " - " + two_week,
            two_week   + " - " + three_week,
            three_week + " - " + four_week,
        ],
        y=[
            product_data[today + " - " + one_week][network],
            product_data[one_week + " - " + two_week][network],
            product_data[two_week + " - " + three_week][network],
            product_data[three_week + " - " + four_week][network]
        ],
        name="Website statistic"
    )
```

The values in `y` are `3, 0, 0, 0`. I have printed them. Tried their type with `type(value)` and it's `class int`. The chart is rendered with `-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1` y axis. The x axis is fine. I tried to replace the `y` values with hardcoded `3,0,0,0` and it worked. Tried to make them ints with `int(value)`, tried to multiply them by 1 `int(value) * 1` and `value * 1`.

Thank you for every advice! The whole code is [here](https://pastebin.com/J51MBpFa)

Comment: Motov If the hard-coded y-values worked fine, the problem has to come from the structure or content of your data source. Is it a dataframe? Could you share some more details?

Comment: It was my bad .. bad structured loop ... Thank you for your time anyway :)